# Undoing a git add -A, no commit, of my home directory

Tags: git

On my first experimentation of git I accidentally forgot to cd to the directory I wanted to do a `git add -A` on resulting in a git add of my whole user directory. Now I have 5000 untracked changes on my git status.  How do I empty this without changing anything on my local computer?  Basically I just want to un-stage these items for commit to git and nothing else. This was a while ago. I have since successfully added and pushed several items to the gitHub repository. Currently, I have nothing in untracked that I will want to commit. Just being cautious, any help appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542753/1030702, but personally I would back up (copy) the dir first *just in case*.

Answer (score 1):

just go for a

```
git reset
```

everything should be fine then.